# AS3: Point for display object x, y?

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest, displayobject

Right now I have a point that I have to update with the x and y of a display object to use with the hitTestPoint object; is there any way I can get a point from a display object without having to make a new point var and continually update its x and y?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
// Your display object you want to get the position from
var something:DisplayObject; 

// Retrieve the position as a Point object
var position:Point = something.transform.pixelBounds.topLeft;
```